# pandas read_csv end of section flag

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a smart/easy way to tell read_csv in pandas not to load data after a certain "end of section" flag?  Or for it to stop if it gets to an empty row?

```
data = pd.read_csv(path, **params)
eos_line = (data['id'] == eos_string).idxmax()
data = data.drop(range(eos_line-2, data.shape[0]))
```

I feel like their ought to be a better way.  Unfortunately I don't know the number of rows or length of the footer I want to skip before calling read_csv.  The data looks roughly something like

```
1,2,3
4,5,6


dont want any data after this line
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

(Note: the -2 is b/c there are actually 2 empty rows before the end of section string, but if read_csv only read until this point I guess dropna() would remove these two rows pretty painlesslly)

Comment: One option is to use nrows, but you need to know that beforehand...

Comment: You're not telling us how you recognize the rows to be excluded: is it simply (nrows-2), or should we detect 2 or more consecutive newlines, or what?

Comment: You're right, good point. I think two consecutive newlines (so one "blank" row) is that I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wes did think of everything!

```
In [40]: data = """A,B,C
   ....: 1,2,3
   ....: 4,5,6
   ....: 7,8,9
   ....: want to skip this
   ....: also also skip this
   ....: """

In [41]: read_csv(StringIO(data), skip_footer=2)
Out[41]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: I could be misunderstanding, but as I understand the OP -- in particular the `eos_line` line -- I think the problem is more like "7,8,9 / want to stop here / 10,20,30 / 40,50,60 / 70,80,90" where we don't know where the end of section strings are beforehand.

Comment: You are correct, but you *could* do ``skip_footer=nrows-section_length-2``, not ideal but will work, not really much support for csv sections as of now

Comment: The data is as DSM says and unfortunately I don't know nrows, section_length or the length of the footer beforehand...

Comment: best bet then is to split the file on the sections then, and make new files to process separately. prob could support a section keyword to do this automatically but it non-trivial